# Eclipse hanging due to DDMS post create init

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Now i know that this question has already been asked before. But I ve tried all of the solutions provided there.

Suddenly eclipse got hung and continuously showing DDMS post create init in progress bar.

I've tried deleting .lock file, cleaning eclipse, closing eclipse, killing adb.exe, re installing sdk.

Is there any other possible solution to resolve this issue. I am dead stuck. Please help!!

My configuration: Win 7 (64 bit) + Eclipse Juno + Java 1.6

Comment: How about restarting PC ?

Comment: Have you change anything in eclipse ?

Answer (score 1):

This just worked for me (I've been dealing with the same issue off and on for a while now)

1. Close eclipse if you already have it open.
2. make sure all adb.exe processes are killed using task manager
3. launch a cmd shell
4. in the shell, run:
   `set ADB_TRACE=1
   adb devices`
5. launch eclipse

Notes for step 4 -
I first tried this without ADB_TRACE=1 and my adb process froze before listing any devices. Why it works with ADB_TRACE debug output is beyond me, but it seems much more consistent with it enabled. *Note: many adb commands start the adb.exe service, keep that in mind in case you need to kill it again.*

Notes for step 5 -
Because the command `adb devices` started the adb service, eclipse attaches to that non-hanging service. If you are still having trouble, try all the steps again but this time launch eclipse with administrator privleges.

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the cause of the problem was that `adb` default port, `5037`,  was in use.

You can check that with

```
netstat -a -o | find "LISTENING"
```

where last column is `PID`.